# The type 'p:PieMenu' AND 'p:PieMenuItem': was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, menu-items

I try to work with a circular menu but I'm getting this error despite following a tutorial:

those are the errors that I get:
[image]

and this is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="GMAO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:p="clr-namespace:GMAO;assembly=GMAO"
        Title="MatserCom GMAO" Height="479" Width="792" Background="#9DB9EB" >
        <StackPanel Height="331" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,56,0,0" Name="stackPanel2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="452">
            <Canvas Background="Black">
                <p:PieMenu x:Name="Menu1"  //I have error at this line with p:PieMenu>
                    <p:PieMenuItem Header="Item 1"> //I have error with all lignes that begin with p:PieMenuItem
                        <p:PieMenuItem Header="Item 1.1" Click="PieMenuItem_Click"/>
                        <p:PieMenuItem Header="Item 1.2" Command="NotACommand"/>
                    </p:PieMenuItem>
                    <p:PieMenuItem Header="Item 2">
                        <p:PieMenuItem Header="Item 2.1" />
                    </p:PieMenuItem>
                    <p:PieMenuItem Header="Item 3">
                        <p:PieMenuItem Header="Item 3.1" />
                    </p:PieMenuItem>
                </p:PieMenu>
            </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>
```

when I try to run the code this is the error I get:

[image]

this is the Assemly project informations

[image]
thanks for help

Comment: I need help pleaze can you help me :'(

Comment: do please check if the element in context are available in assembly GMAO and are public and derives from UIElement. is is possible for you to share the GMAO assembly? so we can have a look

Comment: I have edited my question pushpraj :(

Comment: What is the namespace of your `PieMenu.cs` class?

Comment: are these usercontrols in the GMAO project? if not then you are missing the reference to the assembly containing the actual controls i.e. PieMenu. if these controls are available then even `xmlns:p="clr-namespace:GMAO"` should work. if still does not work then would it be possible for you to post a copy of your project, you may remove any sensitive information.

Comment: @har07 the namespac of PieMenu.c is GMAO ,ok pushpraj I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare `p` prefix this way :

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:GMAO.PieMenu"
```

I assumed that `PieMenu` and `PieMenuItem` are declared in namespace : `GMAO.PieMenu`. And you don't have to specify the assembly name if it is from the same assembly/project.

Comment: thanks har07 but I get a new error after clr-namespace it should take a namespace and PieMenu is not a namespace :/

Comment: thanks guys I just rebuild and clean the project and now it works thanks a lot for help @har07 and pushpraj :D